# How to spilt a bootable linux distro iso file onto multiple dvds or cds?

Tags: boot, dvd, iso-image, centos-6, linux-distributions

I have customized a centOS distro , by including some packages such as VLC,eclipse etc.
but now the size of distro exceeds 7.42 gb.

**I want** to :

- split the large distro iso into multiple small iso files and,
- burn the isos onto portable media like multiple DVDs/CDs (except usb drives).

such that the first iso is bootable & installation process automatically prompts for subsequent DVDs
.i.e. after installing first i am prompted to insert second disk and so on untill last dvd.

i used hjsplit,split,winrar,7zip tools to split the iso & burned same on DVDs,
but when i try booting from **first DVD** error is thrown suggesting "**kernel image not found**".

Please suggest some tools for accomplishing the same.

Comment: Unless the Setup process explicitly support this, it’s impossible. Also, splitting the ISO image accomplishes nothing.

Comment: @DanielB it is possible. Please check the link , here centos distro has been splitted into multiple isos (CentOS-6.5-x86_64-bin-DVD1.iso and  CentOS-6.5-x86_64-bin-DVD2.iso) at http://centosmirror.go4hosting.in/centos/6.5/isos/x86_64/ . i want to achieve the same, please suggest tools for the same.

Comment: You could use a second disk as a repo for those additional files. But you could also just use a double layer DVD and be done with it as your image would fit on a DL DVD.